# Left join not working as expected

Tags: sql-server-2012, left-join

I am using a simple `Left Join` in my query.But the problem query is not working as expected.

**Query Is**

```
select m.* from Menu m
left join MenuRole mr on m.Id=mr.MenuID
where mr.DesignationID=1
```

**Menu Table**

[image]

**MenuRole Table**

[image]

**Output of query**

[image]

The problem is the `Employee data` is missing from the result and the `parentID column` with `Id=0` is also missing.

Comment: add your condition `mr.DesignationID=1 ` next to the On clause not in Where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the where clause, when threre is no match DesignationId is null and therefore DesignationId = 1 is not true.

Try this:

```
select m.* from Menu m
left join MenuRole mr on m.Id=mr.MenuID and mr.DesignationID=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It works great but  new condition is not working  `select m.*,mr.DesignationID from Menu m
left join MenuRole mr on m.Id=mr.MenuID
and mr.DesignationID=1 and m.ParentID<>0`

Comment: @ksg move m.ParentID <> 0 to where clause

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MenuRole is your "Employee" data, then your problem is the m.* select list.  The MenuRole alias is mr.  Try select * or select m.*, mr.*, although it is considered better to retrieve only the fields required.

I am guessing that your role with ParentID = 0 is screened out by your WHERE clause, although some testing is warranted.  It has no match in the visible portion of the MenuRole data, so mr.DesignationID would be null assuming it truly is not present.